# Infinite Loop via Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I've posted about various issues in the past few days trying to configure passport to run via LDAP (using `passport-ldap`) on my Node Express server. Anyway, I've found that the `authenticate` function in `node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js` is running an infinite loop, calling itself over and over again. I've used the Node debugger and put a bunch of `debugger` statements in my code and found that it's sort of repeating itself every time I enter correct login credentials (it correctly redirects to my `login_fail` page when I enter incorrect credentials).

Here's what my debugger looks like on the command line:

```
Bootstrapping server...
< setting up stylus compile
< passport/authenticate
< Bootstrap db connection
< Bootstrap models
< reading model: entry.js
< Initializing EntrySchema
< reading model: user.js
< Initializing UserSchema
< Bootstrap passport
< [Error: Symbol DTraceProviderBindings_module not found.]
< { [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
< { [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
< Bootstrap routes
< passport/authenticate
< Express app started on port 3000
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug> cont
< GET /login 304 36764ms
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:259
 257         // push this failure into the accumulator and attempt authentication
 258         // using the next strategy
 259         debugger;
 260         failures.push({ challenge: challenge, status: status });
 261         attempt(i + 1);
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:87
  85     function allFailed() {
  86 
  87       debugger;
  88 
  89       if (callback) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:99
  97       }
  98 
  99       debugger;
 100       
 101       // Strategies are ordered by priority.  For the purpose of flashing a
debug> cont
< POST /users/session 302 174136ms - 78b
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:259
 257         // push this failure into the accumulator and attempt authentication
 258         // using the next strategy
 259         debugger;
 260         failures.push({ challenge: challenge, status: status });
 261         attempt(i + 1);
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:87
  85     function allFailed() {
  86 
  87       debugger;
  88 
  89       if (callback) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:99
  97       }
  98 
  99       debugger;
 100       
 101       // Strategies are ordered by priority.  For the purpose of flashing a
debug> cont
< POST /users/session 302 9485ms - 78b
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:79
  77   
  78   return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  79     debugger;
  80     var passport = this;
  81     
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:176
 174       var delegate = {};
 175 
 176       debugger;
 177 
 178       delegate.success = function(user, info) {
debug> cont
break in node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:268
 266       if (!layer) { return allFailed(); }
 267     
 268       debugger;
 269 
 270       // Get the strategy, which will be used as prototype from which to create
debug>
```

As you can see, it's repeating the same lines quite a few times (and if I had kept typing `cont`) it would continue doing this until the server timed out. Any ideas why this is happening? Also, side note, I can't figure out why I'm getting that error when I initially start my server; can that be causing the loop? I've Googled that like 3 or 4 times and have yet to find a solution that works.

---

EDIT: I think I found the problem. The code program completely skips over this `res.on` statement as defined in `node_modules/passport-ldap/lib/passport-ldap/strategy.js`:

```
break in node_modules/passport-ldap/lib/passport-ldap/strategy.js:93
  91       }
  92 
  93       debugger
  94       console.log(err)
  95       console.log(r)
debug> cont
< null
< { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 10 }
break in node_modules/passport-ldap/lib/passport-ldap/strategy.js:124
 122         });
 123       });
 124       debugger
 125     });
 126   });
debug>
```

and for reference, here's the function with all my `debugger` statements:

```
Strategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req, options) {
  var self = this;

  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return self.fail(401);
  }

  self.client.bind(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return self.fail(403);
    }

    self.client.search(self._options.base, self._options.search, function(err, r) {
      if (err) {
        return self.fail(403);
      }

      debugger
      console.log(err)
      console.log(r)

      r.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {

        debugger

        var profile = JSON.stringify(entry.object);

        console.log(profile)
        debugger

        self._verify(profile, function(err, user) {

          debugger

          if (err) {
            return self.error(err);
          }

          debugger 

          if (!user) {
            return self.fail(self._challenge());
          }
          debugger

          self.success(user);
        });
      });
      debugger
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: post the code where you're setting up the middleware

Comment: after further investigation i made another edit to my question.

Comment: and which middleware code-- my `passport.js` file or my `routes.js` file?